# Spring Data JPA: how to return empty result when repository method parameter of Collection type is empty?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data JPA v1.10.2
And there's a use-case:

`ClientDao.java`:

```
List<Client> getClientsByUnitsIn(@NonNull Collection<Unit> units);
```

This method generates an SQL query like this one:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE units in (?1)
```

There's a similar case when I add `@Query` annotation for the repository method:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE c.unit IN (?1)")
List<Client> getSpecificClients(@NonNull Collection<Unit> units)
```

But in many cases parameter `units` may be empty. And in such cases the method should return empty result, but it just fail with a message about an erroneous SQL statement.

I use a workaround: adding a default method to the repository like this one:

```
default List<Client> getSpecificClientsOrEmpty(@NonNull Collection<Unit> units){
    if (units.isEmpty) {
        return emptyList();
    }
    return getSpecificClients(units);
}
```

But I don't like this workaround:

- I have to create one extra method for each case
- I have to check that only default method is using in code, as there's no compile-time checking, and if I miss some using, I get a runtime Exception.

Does anybody have a better solution?

Comment: Update: I've found an article just about my case: https://rzymek.github.io/post/jpa-empty-in/   There's a solution, but it doesn't look pretty enough.

Answer (score 3):

1) Write your own query with the boiler plate code in the `getSpecificClients()` repository implementation :

```
public List<Client> getSpecificClients(@NonNull Collection<Unit> units){
    if (units.isEmpty()) {
        return emptyList();
    }
    return em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE c.unit IN (?1)", Unit.class)
             .setParameter(1, units)
             .getResultList();  
}
```

If this pre-processing is a uncommon requirement in your repository, this way should be favored.
It is a little verbose way but it is still acceptable for a handful of cases.

2) Make it in a transverse way with AOP.
Define a `Aspect` to do this processing before each method you need :

```
if (units.isEmpty) {
    return emptyList();
}
```

Note that this way should be used only if the pre-processing requirement occurs frequently enough as it increases the application complexity and the general setup.

3) You could create a generic default method in a base interface repository that accepts a `Function` as parameter to be able to passe to the method any method to execute :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
default<T, U> List<U> selectWithIn(Collection<T> valueForInClause, Function<Collection<T>, List<U>> function) {
    if (valueForInClause.isEmpty()) {
        return new ArrayList<U>();
    }
    return function.apply(valueForInClause);
}
```

In `ClientDAO` class you would have still this one :

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE c.unit IN (?1)")
List<Client> getSpecificClients(@NonNull Collection<Unit> units)
```

And in the client code of the DAO you could invoke the selectWithIn() method in this way :

```
private ClientDAO clientDAO;
...
List<Unit> units = ...;
List<Client> clients = clientDAO.selectWithIn(units, (o) -> clientDAO.getSpecificClients(o));
```

It is not too much verbose, it spares some code lines but I don't like really this way as it makes a little more complex unit tests of the DAO client classes.

Comment: Making own implementation looks ugly. BTW, this requires adding a dummy repository implementation class. As for aspect - thanks, I'll think it over.

Comment: there's a interesting point: when using Spring Data query methods, it works out-of-the-box. But when using Query annotation - it doesn't. Why? May be there's a option to configure in Spring?

Comment: With JPA 2 that provides fluent API, I find not it so ugly. What do you mean by "when using Spring Data query methods" ? Even by using these methods you should handle specifically your optimization : `if (units.isEmpty) {
        return emptyList();
    }`

Comment: Sure, Criteria API from JPA 2 looks nice, but come on, writing `if (...) {return emptyList()` in **every** repository method - that not a good idea :) AOP was invented to avoid such stuff. If I won't find any better way, I'll do AOP.

Comment: I agree with you. AOP is indeed a better choice. But I would introduce it only if the requirement is a little frequent. Setting AOP facilities to intercept 3 or 4 methods is not a good deal. You increase the application complexity and the general setup to spare some code lines.

Comment: Definitely agree, and in my case there're dozens of such methods.

Comment: @omickron Your comment on the question gave me an idea. I updated with a third way. I don't like really but its stays a possibility